# IPython Notebook output cell is truncating contents of my list

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a long list (about 4000 items) whose content is suppressed when I try to display it in an ipython notebook output cell.  Maybe two-thirds is shown, but the end has a "...]", rather than all the contents of the list.  How do I get ipython notebook to display the whole list instead of a cutoff version?

Answer (score 80):

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 4000
```

worked for me

See : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Comment: Nice to see you back at Stackoverflow. Please back up your answer with a link to a reference/documentation. We'd appreciate if you add a (short) description what this configuration option is doing. Consider addressing the asker's question by defining the config with the value 4000 (since the poster says he/she has ~4000 items). Find the edit button below your post. Thank you very much.

Comment: `max_rows` applies to dataframes - `max_seq_items` as per impiyush answer, pertains to lists.

Comment: OP never mentioned pandas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the best solution without mixing javascript or configurations of IPython.

I used that one and didn't worked:

```from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"```

Comment: Probably should mention `pd` is the alias you're using for the pandas library.

Comment: Not sure how pandas relates to the question

Answer (score 39):

I know its a pretty old thread, but still wanted to post my answer in the hope it helps someone.
You can change the number of *max_seq_items* shown by configuring the pandas options as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_seq_items = 2000
```

Comment: where do we put this piece? Tried putting it into my notebook but it still shows me those ...

Comment: depends on the number of items you have. You'll have to play with the number a bit.

Comment: OP never mentioned pandas. It could be a simple long list or numpy array

Answer (score 20):

This should work:

```py
print(str(mylist))
```

Simple!

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I will use print statements.  I was hoping there was a setting in ipython notebook that makes it print the complete contents of the variable when I type its name.

Comment: sorry, to be clear, you don't need the `print` statement if you didn't need it before, it's the conversion to `str()` that's important

Comment: also, there appears to be a `max_seq_length` option in the ipython source but I couldn't find a user-configurable way to edit it; you could try posting a request to the ipython issue tracker

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and information on the max_seq_length option.

Comment: @sziraqui this still works for me with recent versions of jupyterlab

Comment: The output from this is truncated in my version of jupyterlab

Answer (score 14):

The following line prints everything in your list in a readable manner.

```
[print(x) for x in lis]
```

Answer (score 14):

How to disable list truncation in IPython:

1. Create an IPython config file if you don't already have one:

   ```sh
   ipython profile create
   ```
2. Edit the config file to include this line:

   ```py
   c.PlainTextFormatter.max_seq_length = 0
   ```
3. Restart your notebook instance.

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer here?? This is exactly what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 10):

For cases where the output of `print(mylist)` is something like `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]` then `[*mylist]` will expand the items into rows where all items are visible.

Comment: Great answer! This also helps when printing to the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

A quick hack if you're using pandas is to do

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(DataFrame(myList).to_html())
```

Comment: Why is everyone assuming the list is a Df. This doesn't work for numpy array or a simple python list

Comment: This is an old answer. There are better ways now, like using the `display` function from IPython.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to display the whole list in the IPython output cell that doesn't require Pandas:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
x = range(4000)
HTML('<br />'.join(str(y) for y in x))
```

It is also pretty easy to add additional HTML elements and get a more elaborate display.  Clicking to the left of the output cell will now shrink the contents and add a local scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

just use the print command instead of calling the list directly. Like print mylist . It would not truncate then.

Comment: This worked for me, with the additional caveat that I needed to convert to a `list` data type: `print mylist.tolist()`.

Comment: That uses way more memory

Answer (score 0):

Simply print(my_list) works with below settings. Change them accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("max_columns", None) # show all cols
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None) # show full width of showing cols
pd.set_option("expand_frame_repr", False) # print cols side by side as it's supposed to be
pd.options.display.max_seq_items = 200000
pd.options.display.max_rows = 400000


print(my_list) #it will display whole long list
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP is after is `display.max_colwidth` option, which can have either a numeric value or `None` for unlimited.

for example

```
# set the max_colwidth to 100 and output again
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
data.head(3)['Description']
```

[image]