# Print all elements of a dictionary? (It gets cut off at 1000 in my jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I have a dictionary with around 1200 key-valuepairs. I want to be able to go through all of them to check the values, but it cuts off at 1000 (and ends on ...}).

I expect there some setting somewhere to print all of them? I'm doing this in jupyter notebook using python 2.7.

I'm doing Flux Balance Analysis on a model, and the goal is to identify fluxes that does not work - but I find that the value of these fluxes are not necessarily 0, but can simply be an extremely low number.

EDIT: I've just been typing the dict directly into the command line. The function that I used to generate the dict also returned it by default, and that got cut off as well.

Using print str(dict) *works*... But then it becomes unreadable because it's all on one line instead of displaying one key-value pair per line.
Iterating over it with a 'for i in dict, print i, dict[i]' worked though, thanks!

Comment: What are your criteria?  It's almost certainly easier to check them programmatically than to do it yourself

Comment: Well, you could iterate over the [`items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: How do you print the items ? By default print in python should not cut at 1000 items.

Comment: Can you contribute some code?  A diagnosis requires knowledge of all the symptoms.

Comment: Just do `print(str(my_dict))`.

Comment: Even better (for those on 3.5): `print(*my_dict.items(), sep = '\n')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is available in this old question here: [IPython Notebook output cell is truncating contents of my list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388810/ipython-notebook-output-cell-is-truncating-contents-of-my-list)