# Python doesn't process all values of variable in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I use Python 3.x and want to prepare data for `plotly` plot.
I don't know where's the source of my issue. I have for loop:

```
for i in range(2,6):
    cases.append(go.Scattergeo(
        lon = pop['Lon'],
        lat = pop['Lat'],
        text = pop[[i]],
        name = years[i],
        marker = dict(
            size = pop[[i]],            
        ),
    ) )
```

And output: `repr(cases)`

```
"[{'marker': {'size':      1980-12-31\n0          17.0\n1          19.4\n2          24.3\n3          20.7\n4           0.0\n5          27.7\n6          39.6\n7          22.5\n8         224.2\n9          32.3\n10        163.8\n11         20.7\n12          0.0\n13         20.6\n14         24.4\n15         39.8\n16         22.0\n17         35.8\n18        348.6\n19        234.3\n20         53.0\n21         19.7\n22         18.3\n23         32.0\n24        150.1\n25         35.6\n26         33.8\n27         33.9\n28         31.5\n29         35.4\n..          ...\n204        23.5\n205         0.0\n206        19.2\n207       133.5\n208        22.8\n209      1596.1\n210        42.4\n211        17.1\n212        18.3\n213       106.8\n214         0.0\n215        30.9\n216       617.7\n217        23.5\n218        16.6\n219        17.3\n220       196.0\n221        23.9\n222        28.8\n223        17.4\n224        46.8\n225        35.4\n226        62.6\n227        39.0\n228        53.1\n229        33.3\n230         0.0\n231        47.5\n232        37.2\n233        28.3\n\n[234 rows x 1 columns]}, 'name': '1980', 'lon': 0      19.299\n1      19.339\n2      23.000\n3      20.809\n4      19.129\n5      19.360\n6      23.110\n7      15.979\n8      23.159\n9      16.610\n10     19.049\n11     23.290\n12     19.100\n13     22.729\n14     20.429\n15     15.560\n16     19.399\n17     17.470\n18     18.010\n19     18.909\n20     23.490\n21     18.429\n22     16.910\n23     17.569\n24     19.030\n25     19.399\n26     20.620\n27     18.629\n28     19.020\n29     19.129\n        ...
```

The problem is the output is truncated. I thought it was a display issue and saved this variable to file but surprisingly in that file there was exactly the same text as displayed. The value `[234 rows x 1 columns]` shouldn't be in a file.

```
f = open( 'cities.py', 'w' )
f.write( 'dict = ' + repr(cases) + '\n' )
f.close()
```

Sorry, maybe the question is trivial, I use Python from time to time and don't fully understand its strange mechanisms. In every language variable can be truncated on display but not that way. What function should I use to view all values?

Cheers.

Comment: `pop[[i]]` shouldn't do anything, you should be seeing an error

Comment: you're writing `repr(cases)` to a file so it will have the same (truncated) contents. To see the whole dict use something like pprint (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

Comment: repr is limited in size. try converting to json or someother file format.

Comment: Don't put an answer in your question -- just add an answer.  You can accept it, too.

Comment: Ok, but the button suggests to use comment box. I'm always confused in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found solution thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388810/ipython-notebook-output-cell-is-truncating-contents-of-my-list) post. The issue was display option of panda, in this case max rows number. Who would suppose.

`pd.options.display.max_rows = 5000`