# pycharm debugger cannot print all text if message is too long

Tags: pycharm

For example ,if I print `request.META` in django, lost a lot of messages.

```py
# urls.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path
def login(request):
    # print(request.META)
    # print(str(request.META))
    return HttpResponse('yes')


urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login),
]
```

`print` in code auto runs will get full message.

If manually input code in Debug console, will not get full message.

How to fix it ?

```
In[1]: print(request.META)
# lost data in the end of line
{'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'ANDROID_HOME': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk', 'ANDROID_SDK_HOME': 'C:\\Android', 'APPCODE_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\appcode.vmoptions', 'APPDATA': 'D:\\wgf\\AppData\\Roaming', 'CLION': 'D:\\ProgramData\\CLion 2021.2.1\\bin;', 'CLION_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\clion.vmoptions', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'NEWHOME-PC', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'DATAGRIP_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\datagrip.vmoptions', 'DATASPELL_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\dataspell.vmoptions', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'djapp1.settings', 'DOT_SAGE': '/dot_sage', 'DRIVERDATA': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData', 'FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL': 'https://storage.flutter-io.cn', 'FPS_BRO...
In[2]: print(str(request.META))
{'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'ANDROID_HOME': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk', 'ANDROID_SDK_HOME': 'C:\\Android', 'APPCODE_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\appcode.vmoptions', 'APPDATA': 'D:\\wgf\\AppData\\Roaming', 'CLION': 'D:\\ProgramData\\CLion 2021.2.1\\bin;', 'CLION_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\clion.vmoptions', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'NEWHOME-PC', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'DATAGRIP_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\datagrip.vmoptions', 'DATASPELL_VM_OPTIONS': 'E:\\ja-netfilter-all\\vmoptions\\dataspell.vmoptions', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'djapp1.settings', 'DOT_SAGE': '/dot_sage', 'DRIVERDATA': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData', 'FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL': 'https://storage.flutter-io.cn', 'FPS_BRO...
```

Comment: Does `print(request.META)` print the full message?

Comment: Still not. Updated thread.

Comment: Try this one more trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/23485105/315168