# Copied code from a cell in a Jupyter notebook on Databricks is shortened and partially replaced by three dots (...)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

When copying code extracts using `ctrl + c` from one Jupyter notebook cell and pasting it using `ctrl + v` in another cell, the copied code gets partially omitted and, the omitted part gets replaced by three dots (the single character three dots `…`). I am running the notebook in a Databricks workspace (which is accessible through a web browser).

For example, suppose that a cell in the notebook contains the following code:

```
spark.sql(f"""
select 
  0 as somecolumn_0,
  1 as somecolumn_1,
  2 as somecolumn_2,
  3 as somecolumn_3,
  4 as somecolumn_4,
  5 as somecolumn_5,
  6 as somecolumn_6,
  7 as somecolumn_7,
  8 as somecolumn_8,
  9 as somecolumn_9,
  10 as somecolumn_10,
  0 as somecolumn_11,
  1 as somecolumn_12,
  2 as somecolumn_13,
  3 as somecolumn_14,
  4 as somecolumn_15,
  5 as somecolumn_16,
  6 as somecolumn_17,
  7 as somecolumn_18,
  8 as somecolumn_19,
  9 as somecolumn_20,
  10 as somecolumn_21
""")
```

When I copy the code using `ctrl + c` and try to paste it in another cell using `ctrl + v`, the following code is pasted instead:

```
spark.sql(f"""
select 
  0 as somecolumn_0,
  1 as somecolumn_1,
  2 as somecolumn_2,
  3 as somecolumn_3,
  4 as somecolumn_4,
  5 as somecolumn_5,
  6 as somecolumn_6,
  7 as somecolumn_7,
…  7 as somecolumn_18,
  8 as somecolumn_19,
  9 as somecolumn_20,
  10 as somecolumn_21
""")
```

Mind that copying by `right click > copy` does produce the correct result, even when pasted with `ctrl + v`.

The expected result is result is evidently that the code from the first snippet is pasted exactly as-is. The issue doesn't seem to be linked specifically to the notebook, as other users are perfectly capable of copying and pasting the code within the notebook using the described keyboard shortcuts. For me specifically, the issue persists in other notebooks. I also tried using different keyboards to eliminate hardware causes.

Any thoughts what can be the reason of this, and how to fix it?

Comment: You may want to try some of the suggestions about lists or strings in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23485105/8508004). It seems possibly related to [list truncation discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570414/8508004). Plus, and **maybe more importantly**, I'm not seeing this in actual vanilla Jupyter running on a remote linux machine accessed inside the Chrome browser. Did you try the same stuff on a different machine with a different browser yet?

Comment: One day after the fact, the issue seems resolved automatically. Not sure what triggered this, and what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have exact same issue and have only noticed it today. Will be reaching out to our Databricks rep about it. Meanwhile, the only workaround that works for me is to use Copy from the context pop-up. I will update the answer once I get additional details.

Hope this helps!

[Redundant context menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jquHP.png)

[Annoying triple popup in top right when Ctrl-C is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeUu2.png)

Comment: Great, thanks! I also have the triple popup when using `ctrl + c`.